# jquery page navigator with scroll and drag

Tags: jquery

i create a page navigator with jquery.
is a thumbnail of the page with a box of aspect ratio (1/10)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/Vmurd/1/)**

I can drag the box #screen and animate the window scroll, and I can scroll the window and update the box position.

my problem is the use of both actions..when I drag the box.. the scroll go crazy!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling also ocurs on the **#screen** frame because of it's absolute position. If you fix it, it will work better:

```
#screen {
    border:1px solid red;
    position:fixed;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Also the animation seems to be not such a good idear. If you change it to normal scrolling it nearly works.

```
$('html').scrollTop(currentPos.top).scrollLeft(currentPos.left);
```

The rest is fine-tuning and playing around with the margin.

Comment: thank you @jan! this is the update situation. if i drag the div there are also same problemes.. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vmurd/6/)

Comment: Hey Giovanni, I tested it without the ui-dragging-function and then it's god clear: If you change the scroll position the mousedown event changes the pageX and pageY attribute. So you have to subtract the scroll-Position from the page position. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vmurd/12/)